# How can i access data in a list via indexing

Tags: python, list

using the list below...Assignment is to print 'Earth' & 'Uranus' using list zero-based indexing but am getting it wrong

```
`solar_system = ["Jupiter", ["Uranus", ["Earth"], "Saturn"]]`
```

I have made research on google and some coding website and coding group(telegram) but can't still understand it despite the solution i was given which is..
 `print(solar_system[1][1][0])`

Using the solution i got, it worked out but based on how i understand list indexing i still can't comprehend it.

Comment: Look at `solar_system[1]` and you'll see it's just a list that can be indexed... so then look at `solar_system[1][1]` and again, you'll see a list... and finally, look at `solar_system[1][1][0]`...

Comment: That is an odd way to construct the list.  Why does it contain a sub-list, which itself contains another sub-list?  What is the purpose?  Is this a practice problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What part don't you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Lists are simply accessed by their index The same goes for the values in the nested lists, you access them by first accessing the nested list then the index of the value.

```
master_list = [[1, 2], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]

print(master_list[0]) # gives us [1, 2]
print(master_list[1]) # gives us [[5, 6], [7, 8]]
print(master_list[1][0]) # gives us [5, 6]
print(master_list[1][0][0]) # gives us 5
```